# Weather data displayed with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

i'm currently trying to plot weather data with gnuplot using a text document containing a utc timestamp in the first column, and the temperature in the second and third.

`set term png size 1920,660
set output "Today.png"
set datafile missing '0'
set ylabel "Temperature"
set grid ytics
set timefmt "%s"
set format x "%H:%M:%S"
set xdata time
set xtics rotate
plot "Data.dat" using 1:2 with lines lt rgb "red" t "Inside", "Data2.dat" using 1:3 with lines lt rgb "blue" t "Outside"`

This is working and displaying the graphs except for one thing:
The data is automatically updated every couple hours. So when creating the image at 10 am it will display data from 0-10 am. Instead I want it to always display one complete day at a time, so over the course of the day, you can see the graph "grow" from left to right.

I tried inserting the following code:

`set xrange ["00:00:00":"23:59:59"]`

but it does not display anything then.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish that?

Comment: The string given to `xrange` must be either a string, which is then parsed using the format of the `set timefmt`, or an integer, which is interpreted as kind of timestamp.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working when inserting the timestamp for midnight of the current and the following day. One more thing, on my raspberry pi i was running an old version of gnuplot, version 4.6.6 and it is not working there. After upgrading to the current version 5.0.5 it works.

Comment: You could probably automate this using `stats` and gnuplot's `tm_*` functions, but that requires more knowledge about your data file. Does it only contain data from one day?

Comment: No its data from several days now, got that weather station 2 weeks ago, and growing. I put all that into a little perl script and than displaying it via a local apache server from my rpi within the local network